# How do I find a template?

Tags: theming, nodes, 6

How I determine which template or form is responsible for processing node of page with this URL: mysite.com/node/node-number/edit ?

I think, that Drupal find the template of edit in this files:

```
page-node-edit.tpl.php
page-node- node-number.tpl.php
page-node.tpl.php
page.tpl.php
```

However, in my theme folder I have only `page.tpl.php` without the code of edit template, but edit template is worked.

And in template.php i heve this preprodsse_node:

```
function my_theme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
    $node = $vars['node'];
    switch ($node->type) {
        case 'page':
            break;
    }
}
```

Now I think that the CCK module to generate this form. I can change one field or a behavior of the form?

P.S.

I need to change some input in edit form. And I can't use a different version of Drupal :(

Comment: The true answer of my question is: CCK module create a template for edit node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the default value of fields in node edit form. You should looking on any *.tpl.php files. You have to define your own custom module and use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6.x)

You can use this if-statement inside the hook function.

```php
// remember change [nodetype] to the one you want to alter.
if($form_id == 'nodetype_node_form'){
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How i can to change form action after user click submit?

Comment: You can define a new submit function and append into the form submit array.
`$form['#submit'][] = 'your_form_submit_function'`

Comment: Now if the form is submitted, CCK update some field in mysql database. I need to change this, because  in one form input contains three values, and this values need to be recorded in three fields in databse.

Comment: You can retrieve the submitted value in `$form_state['#values']`. You can do whatever you want then.

Comment: I would recommend you post a new question with more details of your case. Comment is not a good place for answering long question with lack of information.

Comment: Ok! I create this question [link] (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/203368/how-to-edit-cck-form-at-drupal-6). And I thank you for your answer