# How to edit CCK form?

Tags: forms, 6

How I change node edit form, which created by CCK module?

Now if the form is submitted, CCK update some field in mysql database. I need to change this, because in one form input contains three values, and this values need to be recorded in three fields in databse. How can I do this?

Jimmy Ko said, that I can retrieve the submitted value in `$form_state['#values']`, but I don’t know in what .php file I can do this?

Comment: You should keep in mind that Drupal 6 is no longer supported by the community, and all Drupal 6 sites should plan to upgrade to Drupal 7 or 8 soon.

Comment: I know it, but site does not have the ability to update to Drupal 7 or newest version

Answer (score 2):

For achieving this goal you have to implement [hook_nodeapi](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6.x)

In `presave` operation you can get desired value.

Example code you can get from the [D6 release](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples/releases?api_version%5B%5D=87) of the [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give exaple of this hook?

Comment: And at that php file i need implement this hook?